LINE app only resends first picture. How to detect and deal with?
In the LINE app chats, I was offline when sending a group of photos. Now I am online and press the swirl and choose "resend".
The time appears, meaning the resend worked, but my friend says he only got one photo! I am at my wit's end.


Close the LINE app.
Restart the LINE app.
Visit that chat again.
You will see that block of pictures you thought you all successfully sent now broken down into individual pictures. And you will see only the first possesses a time stamp.
Now you can do the resend action on each picture one at a time, and see the individual time stamps next to each photo confirming that it was actually sent.

P.S., you also asked "How to detect." Well, there is no way to detect it. Just keep a healthy suspicion and double-check all pictures were sent each time as per the steps above.

P.S., too bad that it is too difficult to send a bug report to the LINE Corporation these days. They only accept photos. One would need to make a photo of this web article!
